# System doesn't find the correct version of Python?

Tags: python, macos, shell, homebrew

Installed Python 2.7.5 through Homebrew on Mac OS X. How does the following make sense?

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jan 15 2015)
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011)
$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011)
```

Looks like running `python` the OS uses `/usr/bin/python` (v2.7.1), but that contradicts the result of the `which python` command, which shows it should use `/usr/local/bin/python` (v2.7.5).

Any ideas?

Comment: try running `hash -r`, then running `python` again. Does the correct version start this time?

Comment: @MattDMo Whoa that worked. But why? =)

Comment: @melonccoli This might help to explain: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_%28Unix%29